# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException error exception

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

The problem I have is that in Dbeaver, the database manager my query, if it gives me nice results:

```
SELECT * FROM ENVIO_REMESA er 
INNER JOIN REMESA r 
ON er.REMESA_ID = r.ID WHERE er.REMESA_ID = 1;
```

On the other hand, in Hibernate, it does not give me any results, and I get the 500 error . er.remesa is the equivalent of er.REMESA_ID . My query in repo is this:

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM EnvioRemesa er INNER JOIN Remesa r ON er.remesa = r.id WHERE er.remesa=?1")
List<Remesa> findRemesaByEnvio(Integer idEnvio, PageRequest pageReq);
```

Anyone know what might be happening?

EDIT 2:

It's throwing this error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException
```

Both entities

**Remesa.java:**

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "remesa",fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<EnvioRemesa> envioRemesa;
```

**EnvioRemesa.java**

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "remesa_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Remesa remesa;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the server logs what error is being thrown?

Comment: Only gives me 500 error @OHGODSPIDERS

Comment: 500 is a http code that is send to the client when a server error happens. It itself is useless for debugging as it doesn't tell you anything. In the server itself you should always have some way to find out what caused the server to send this 500 response to the client.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException error exception